# Is it possible to make Simplex, Perlin and Worley noise using shader nodes?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

I want to create classic Simplex, Perlin, and Worley noise using shader nodes.

The `Noise Texture` says it is a *fractal Perlin noise* but I want the classic Perlin noise.

The `Voronoi Texture` says it *evaluates a Worley Noise* but I want the classic Worley noise.

I did not get any node equivalent to *Simplex* noise.

Is it possible to create these noises procedurally?

Answer (score 0):

Blender's Shader Graph has a [Script Node](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/osl.html) which supports a broad spectrum of the [Open Shading Language](https://github.com/AcademySoftwareFoundation/OpenShadingLanguage).  The Open Shading Language enables loops, for example, which are a powerful tool in shader programming. With this (I claim), it should be possible to generate your desired noise types (without knowing the formulas in detail now).